# How to create a line graph of 2 variables for 3 entities through the years?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an excel with data of 3 countries, and their values of Marriages and Divorces from 1960-2019 and i need to create a graph with y=value of each variable for each country through the years, I have tried doing this but I can't seem to make it work and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. (I have to use ggplot, it's a class requirement)

```
library(ggplot2)
Anos <- factor(CASDIV$Ano)
names(CASDIV)



colors <- c("Casamentos: Croácia" = "Blue", "Casamentos: Irlanda" = "Orange",
            "Casamentos: Malta" = "Yellow", "Divórcios: Croácia" = "red",
            "Divórcios: Irlanda" = "Green", "Divórcios: Malta" = "Brown")

ggplot(CASDIV, aes(x= Ano))+
  geom_line(data=subset(CASDIV, País== "HR - Croácia"), aes(y=CASDIV$Casamentos, color = "Casamentos : Croácia"), size = 0,01)+
  geom_line(data=subset(CASDIV, País== "IE - Irlanda"), aes(y=CASDIV$Casamentos, color = "Casamentos : Irlanda"), size=0,01)+
  geom_line(data = subset(CASDIV, País=="MT - Malta"), aes(y=CASDIV$Casamentos, color = "casamentos: Malta"), size=0,01)+
  geom_line(data=subset(CASDIV, País== "HR - Croácia"), aes(y=CASDIV$Divórcios, color = "Divórcios : Croácia"), size=0,01)+
  geom_line(data=subset(CASDIV, País == "IE - Irlanda"), aes(y=CASDIV$Divórcios, color = "Divórcios : Irlanda"), size=0,01)+
  geom_line(data=subset(CASDIV, País=="MT - Malta"), aes(y=CASDIV$Divórcios, color = "Divórcios : Malta"), size=0,01)+
  labs(x="Anos", y= "Valor", Colour = "Legenda") +
  scale_color_manual(values= colors)
```

MRE:

```
2017,HR - Croácia,20310,6265
2018,HR - Croácia,19921,6125
2019,HR - Croácia,19761,5936
2017,IE - Irlanda,22021,0
2018,IE - Irlanda,21053,0
2019,IE - Irlanda,20313,0
2016,MT - Malta,3034,371
2017,MT - Malta,2934,312
2018,MT - Malta,2831,349
2019,MT - Malta,2674,354
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you mind providing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.  To post your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 10))` for the first 10 rows of data.

Comment: ... this said: As a general rule get rid of `CASDIV$...`. Simply use e.g. `aes(y=Casamentos, ..)`. As far as I can tell using `CASDIV$Casamentos` will probably result in an error.

Comment: So, this is an excerpt of the data im using dput(head(CASDIV$Casamentos,5))
c(36761, 36634, 36149, 33976, 35965)
> dput(head(CASDIV$Divórcios,5))
c(4811, 5057, 4883, 5114, 5217)                                                                                          > dput(head(Anos,5))
structure(1:5, .Label = c("1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", 
"1965", "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", 
"1973", "1974", "1975", "1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", "1980", 
), class = "factor"), Sorry for the bad formatting, i cut some of the years in the Anos class to fit, thanks

Comment: when i run this i receive a "Error: `stat` must be either a string or a Stat object, not a numeric vector" notification, but I'm not using stat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. First, as I already mentioned in my comment you use `aes(y = CASDIV$..` in your code which is not recommended and which in your case will result in an error. Second: You use a comma as decimal separator in `size=0,01` which is the reason for the mysterious `Error: stat must be either a string or a Stat object, not a numeric vector" notification`. Always use `.` as the decimal mark. Finally, while you took the right approach for the colors you have to make sure that the labels you use inside `aes()` are the same as in your color vector.

Note: A size of `0.01` makes the lines nearly invisible so I switched to `0.1`.

Using some fake random data to mimic your real data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

CASDIV <- data.frame(
  Ano = seq(1960, 2020, 10),
  País = rep(c("HR - Croácia", "IE - Irlanda", "MT - Malta"), each = 7),
  Casamentos = runif(21),
  Divórcios = runif(21)
)
Anos <- factor(CASDIV$Ano)

colors <- c("Casamentos: Croácia" = "Blue", "Casamentos: Irlanda" = "Orange",
            "Casamentos: Malta" = "Yellow", "Divórcios: Croácia" = "red",
            "Divórcios: Irlanda" = "Green", "Divórcios: Malta" = "Brown")

ggplot(CASDIV, aes(x= Ano))+
  geom_line(data=subset(CASDIV, País== "HR - Croácia"), aes(y=Casamentos, color = "Casamentos: Croácia"), size = 0.1)+
  geom_line(data=subset(CASDIV, País== "IE - Irlanda"), aes(y=Casamentos, color = "Casamentos: Irlanda"), size=0.1)+
  geom_line(data = subset(CASDIV, País=="MT - Malta"), aes(y=Casamentos, color = "Casamentos: Malta"), size=0.1)+
  geom_line(data=subset(CASDIV, País== "HR - Croácia"), aes(y=Divórcios, color = "Divórcios: Croácia"), size=0.1)+
  geom_line(data=subset(CASDIV, País == "IE - Irlanda"), aes(y=Divórcios, color = "Divórcios: Irlanda"), size=0.1)+
  geom_line(data=subset(CASDIV, País=="MT - Malta"), aes(y=Divórcios, color = "Divórcios: Malta"), size=0.1)+
  labs(x="Anos", y= "Valor", Colour = "Legenda") +
  scale_color_manual(values= colors)
```

[image]

While your code works, it is probably not the most efficient. Using some data wrangling you could simplify the plotting code considerably:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

CASDIV_long <- CASDIV %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Ano, País)) %>% 
  mutate(color = paste(name, substring(País, 5), sep = ":"))

ggplot(CASDIV_long, aes(x= Ano)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = value, color = color), size = .1) +
  labs(x="Anos", y= "Valor", Colour = "Legenda") +
  scale_color_manual(values= colors)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks!! I can't upvote your answer, not enough reputation but thanks for the help, I understand now what I did wrong. And with all honestly I don't fully comprehend the more effective way you suggested yet, but hopefully with more experience I'll be able to be more efficient.